# Selecting smallest value from a list of coordinate tuples

Tags: python, list, select, tuples, min

I am trying to iterate through a list of tuples like this:

```
[(0, 0.0083553666846612491), (1, 0.0054999681509501821)]
```

and find the smallest value on the right hand side of the tuple and then save the accompanying left hand side value to a variable.

What would the best way to go about this problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument to the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20functions#min) function to find the tuple with the smallest second value:

```
>>> l = [(0, 0.0083553666846612491), (1, 0.0054999681509501821)]
>>> smallest = min(l, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
>>> smallest
1
```

Here a lambda expression is used to select the second item of each tuple and `min` uses that value in its comparisons. `min()` returns the full tuple, so you can extract the first item using `[0]`.

You can also use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> smallest = min(l, key=itemgetter(1))[0]
>>> smallest
1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
min_tuple = min(your_list, key=lambda item: item[1])
```

So we are providing the method for tuple comparition

Comment: You were like only 3 minutes late. Normally, I would upvote both answers, but [mhawke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40456054/1218980) provided much more details while you provided none. It's highly encouraged to provide a description of the solution you're proposing, not only a one-liner.

Comment: I was using the phone app, where every letter counts (who like to write essays on the phone). Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, writing answers on a phone is far from the best.